# Git command "add -p" on all files

Tags: git

I need some combination of 'git add -p' and 'git add -A' command.

I need to review all changes, not files already included into git. What I can do?

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add all new files to the staging area (*bash* syntax):

```
git add `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard`
```

Then you add with patch option normally:

```
git add -p
```

Comment: @asiniy There isn't AFAIK