# How can I get git add -p to allow me to review untracked files

Tags: git

I would like to have `git add -p` allow me **to review** not only the changes in the modified files, but in the **untracked** files.

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048397/git-command-add-p-on-all-files) but unlike in that case, **I do not want to stage all untracked files**. I want to be given the option to stage or to not stage the addition of some of the untracked files.

I tried to do `git add -p -A` but this only went through all the changes in the modified files, and quit, without showing me the new untracked files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't—but the change in the untracked file, if you `git add` it, is that the *entire file is new*, so if you *could*, you'd just get one giant diff hunk, saying "this file is all-new".

Just view the untracked file and decide whether to `git add` it.  If it should *never* be added, consider telling Git to shut up about it by listing it in an [ignore file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8527597/1256452).  (But note that listing a file *after* it's added is too late: Git is already tracking it and no longer looks for an entry in a "shut up about these files" file.)

Comment: Thanks for the information! It's just that there were several untracked files I wanted to add, and not some others (that aren't ready/finished yet) and I couldn't just do a blanket `git add ./path/to/stuff/` because some of the files inside weren't ready yet either. I have found that `git add -i` allows me to add untracked files in an easier way (without having to write out the whole path) but it was a big buggy (it just hanged and wouldn't quit), so I'll just have to add the files by hand it seems :) I don't mind doing it but it would be nice to have a way to do this faster!

Comment: Yeah, I've never quite gotten the hang of `git add -i`. I find it easier to run `git status` or `git status --short`, save the output to a temp file if needed, and turn the temp file into appropriate `git add`s and gitignore entries.